# How use multiple @Embedded in same entity?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an embeddable entity in a java web app as follow:

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
public class Address {
   private String street;
   private String alley;
   private int postCode;
}
```

I use a embedded field in another entity as follow:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    @Embedded
    private Address home;

    @Embedded
    private Address work;
}
```

When I run application, Occur error :

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:
>   my.package.User column: alley(should be mapped with insert="false"
>   update="false").

**How can I fix it?**

***note:***

- I can't use `@AttributeOverrides`.
- I'm using hibernate 5.2.10.

**update:** 
I use configs in `applicationContext.xml` as follow:

```
<bean id="mainSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
    <property name="packagesToScan"> 
        <list> 
            <value>my.package</value> 
        </list> 
    </property> 

    <property name="hibernateProperties"> 
        <props> 
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">public</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy">org.hibernate.boot.‌?model.naming.Impli‌?ci‌?tNamingStrategyCompo‌nentPathImpl</prop> 
        </props> 
    </property> 
</bean> 

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mainSessionFactory"/> 
</bean>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA Multiple Embedded fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331744/jpa-multiple-embedded-fields)

Comment: @wolverine The version of Hibernate has changed

Comment: what is your table structure?

Comment: @wolverine I can't understand you

Comment: You will be mapping the `User` entity to a database table right, what is the schema of that table, also may I know why you can't use `@AttributeOverrides`

Comment: @wolverine its public schema(postgresql). I can't use `@AttributeOverrides` because I use very `@Embedded` in other entities, and I want to solve all at once.

Comment: I am asking, are you storing the address details in a separate table or in the same table, i.e. user table.

Comment: @wolverine in the same table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154684/discussion-between-wolverine-and-morteza-malvandi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem and I want to share the answer:

The key point is defining `implicitNamingStrategy`:

```
<bean id="mfNamingStrategy"
class="org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl" />
<bean id="mainSessionFactory"
   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="implicitNamingStrategy" ref="mfNamingStrategy" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties"> 
        <props> 
            ...
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy">org.hibernate.boot.‌?model.naming.Impli‌?ci‌?tNamingStrategyCompo‌nentPathImpl</prop> -->
        </props> 
    </property> 
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve using @AttributeOverrides

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
public class Address {
   private String street;
   private String alley;
   private int postCode;
}



@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
       @AttributeOverride(name="street",column=@Column(name="home_street")),
       @AttributeOverride(name="alley",column=@Column(name="home_alley")),
       @AttributeOverride(name="postCode",column=@Column(name="home_postCode"))
    })
    private Address home;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
       @AttributeOverride(name="street",column = @Column(name="work_street")),
       @AttributeOverride(name="alley",column=@Column(name="work_alley")),
       @AttributeOverride(name="postCode",column=@Column(name="work_postCode"))
    })
    private Address work;
}
```

**UPDATE:** 
   If you don't want to use @AttributeOverrides then try overring hibernate naming strategy using `ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl.INSTANCE`

Comment: How can I override hibernate naming strategy?

Comment: try adding the following property `<prop key="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy">org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl</prop>`